# Activation Mail for registered users MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, encryption, smtp

I create a new user on the site.
The user must be in active.
I must send a *activation* e-mail to the registered e-mail address *with a link* to activate the account.
This link must be *encrypted* so that it can not be intercepted.
When user clicks the link and system activated the account and log him in.
My `user` table contains:

`ID`,
`Username`,
`Password`,
`ContactInfoID`,
`AddressID`,
`Role`

My `ContactInformation` table:

`ID`,
`Email`,
`Tel`,
`Cell`,
`Fax`,
`Name`,
`Surname`

`user.ContactInfoID` is my `ContactInformation.ID` field.

Here is how I add a user:

```
UserEmailCompare ma = new UserEmailCompare();
ma.email = db.ContactInformations.Where(x => x.EMail != null).Select(x => x.EMail);

if (model.Password != model.PasswordCheck)
{
    return ErrorResponse("The password you have entered does not match");
}
else 
{
    if (ma.email.Contains(model.Email))
    {
        return ErrorResponse("The e-mail address you have entered has already been registered");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user;
            ContactInformation info;

            info = new ContactInformation()
            {
                EMail = model.Email
            };

            db.ContactInformations.Add(info);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var only = db.ContactInformations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EMail == model.Email).ID;
            if (model.UserID == 0)
            { //add
                user = new User()
                {
                    Username = model.Username,
                    Password = Globals.CreateHashPassword(model.Password),
                    ContactInfoID = only
                };

                db.Users.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me to go further.
I have got classes to send e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need a `gmail` account, with the name you like, from which activation mail will be sent

You will need to Import and use `System.Net.Mail`

Here is a sample code

```
const string accountName = "";                             // # Gmail account name
const string password = "";                                // # Gmail account password
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

smtp.Credentails = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(accountName, password);

mail.From = new MailAddress("youremailaddress@gmail.com"); // # Remember to change here with the mail you got
mail.To.Add(model.Email);                                  // # Email adress to send activation mail
mail.Subject = "Activation Mail";
mail.Body = "Hey there, click this link for activation";   // # You will need to change here with HTML containing a link (which contains a generated activation code)
mail.IsHtml = true;

smtp.Send(mail);
```

---

This was about *sending a mail* to a given email address. For the whole activation process you can follow these steps:

- Create a `HTML` *template* for activation mail body containing parameters for activation link and user information
- Add `IsActive` and `ActivationCode` fields to `User` table
- Implement activation code generation logic or use `Guid`
- After sending mail successfuly, update `User` table setting sent activation code
- You need an activation page, which will receive generated activation code with querystring and *activate* user (setting `IsActive` to true)

Comment: I have already created this class. Can you help me move forward?

Comment: @Hydro I didn't include *encryption* which i see unnecessary in this phase or any other. Just *encrypt* the query string values if you must (such as memberId and activation code)

Comment: What type of fields should the `IsActive` and `ActivationCode` fields be?

Comment: @Hydro what type should they be? IsActive -> yes is active, no isn't active. ActivationCode -> read 3rd list item about the activation logic. What type should they be you think ?

Comment: I sorted the previouse out thanks. What I would Like to ask is. How doe I pass more then one parameter in the url. This is what i have: `<a href=\"http://localhost:50024/User/Validation?key=" + g.ToString() + "\">link</a>` but I need to pass the userid and password to.

Comment: @Hydro search for `QueryString` for the answer, but i wonder why are you passing the *password* ? I suggest you keep it as `http://localhost:50024/User/Validation?key='SomeKey'&userId='UserId'`. Mailing the password and passing it in querystring is not very good practice. You might even want to encrypt `UserId`

Comment: I have removed the password parameter as it is not needed. How would I encrypt the `UserId`?

Comment: Google it after you finished and tested whole activation process ;) For now just concentrate on activation